# Python equivalant for 'pat2cwav'

Tags: python, matlab, wavelet

'pat2cwav' is a Matlab function which is used to build wavelet from a given pattern. Is there a similar function in Python or any octave based toolbox?

reference:http://in.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/ref/pat2cwav.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard analogue for that function in python.
You need to use some math libs and matplotlib for plotting.

Check this out:
https://github.com/aaren/wavelets